# Использование html-шаблонов для C++ Builder

Tags: html, c++, c++builder

Использую `C++ Builder`, возникла необходимость генерации `html`-страниц на основе данных из `DataSource`, как лучше это организовать? Если я правильно понимаю, по аналогии с шаблонами в `CMS`, должны быть `html`-шаблоны с переменными - скелет страницы, но данные могут быть повторяющимися (строки в таблице, например), т.е. нужно в коде генерировать эти куски кода с заполнением данными в цикле уже с тегами. Потом заполнять шаблон и сохранять во временный `html`-файл для последующего отображения. Есть ли какой-то более элегантный способ?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри как тут сделано: [cjCms](http://github.com/sitev/cjCms), может понравится...

Там есть такая замечательная функция

```
void WebTemplate::out(String tag, String s);
```

выводит в тег, строку... Ну а дальше дело техники... Если что стучись в скайп/аську